# why doesn't visual studio solution bind to visualsvn anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, visualsvn

Although i see the VisualSvn menu in visual stuido 2010, my solutions no longer bind to visualsvn.

i just [installed thi patch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/25/patch-available-for-cut-or-copy-displaying-insufficient-memory-error-in-vs-2010.aspx) to visual studio 2010 as i was seeing this memory error popup all the time.  Since installing it, my solution no longer "binds" to visual svn.

When i now click on any of the visualsvn menu items it says **"Couldn't determine absolute path of C:".**

Has anyone seen this or have any solution for getting visual svn working .  I don't fully know if its related to this patch above but that is when this issue started happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

upgrading to the latest visualsvn (2.0.5) seemed to have fixed my problem.